# Object doesn't support this property or method 'eq' Internet Explorer only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

This snippet of code...

```
sourcerow = $('#' + recordid);
item = sourcerow.find('td');
item.eq(1).text(itwcode);
```

Works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

But today I discovered that IE throws an error on this line - `item.eq(1).text(itwcode);`

The error is `Object does not support this property or method 'eq'`

I thought maybe 'item' was not properly being recognised as a jquery element so I tried this..

```
sourcerow = $('#' + recordid);
item = $(sourcerow.find('td'));
item.eq(1).text(itwcode);
```

Same error,  so I tried this...

```
sourcerow = $('#' + recordid);
item = sourcerow.find('td');
$(item).eq(1).text(itwcode);
```

But now IE throws an error from inside the jquery library...

`Invalid calling object jquery-1.9.1.min.js line 3 character 7849`

Is there a way to solve or get around this error?

**EDIT:**  As suggested by mikakun in the comments, I changed the name of the variable from 'item' to something else ('rowitem') and the code now works in IE.  It's odd though because item is not a reserved word, and it worked fine in other browsers.

**EDIT 2** Alternatively - leaving the name as 'item' but adding the 'var' keyword also fixed the code.  item is used in another scope (but in a very similar way so same type)

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger for IE? Nothing about the code you posted seems abnormal.

Comment: It occurs on my ie 9 and a colleague's IE 8

Greg,  IE actually highlights the offending line in the debugger.  I will try stepping through though.. see which line sends me into jquery library to throw the error.

Comment: Well, don't try stepping through jQuery. I was just curious to see what the return value of the call to `sourcerow.find("td")` is.

Comment: You know, it might be that `sourcerow.find("td")` isn't finding as many TD tags as you might think in IE, which could point to an HTML syntax error causing the DOM tree to be different in IE.

Comment: Wasn't going to step through jquery... just until the line in my own code which was the last line to be executed before IE finds the error in jquery.  I'm not used to IE's debugger so I'll see what I can do.

Comment: can you try this and see if it solves your problem  - $(item).eq(1).text(itwcode);

Comment: Already tried that Allan.  See my question :)

Comment: Greg,  console shows 'function item() {[native code]}' for 'item'.    Same if I do console.log(item)

Comment: `console.log(item)` (to look in ie console obviously

Comment: change your var name ! (ie have a function item declared somewhere it seems

Comment: Changed the var name.  That worked!   Thanks mikakun.

(Strange that it worked fine in other browsers)

Comment: ... further to that... item is declared in a different scope elsewhere, but it seemed that was interfering (even though it was declared in a different scope)   I have renamed back to 'item' in this scope, but added 'var' to redefine it.  This also works.

Comment: Why are you doing `$(item)` when it is already a jQuery object??

Comment: I wasn't.  That was just something I tried in an attempt to make it work.  In case it somehow wasn't being recognised as a jquery object by IE.  Please read the question carfully!

Answer (score 0):

In a practical sense, and if you use compilation for your project, you might consider to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support